# curl post form data is not working

Tags: php, curl

I want to post form data to a service but it shows some error with form parameters, this is my curl script sample:

```
<?php 
//       header('Content-Type:application/json');

       $data = array();
       $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


       $user= $data["username"];
       $pass= $data["password"];


       $form_data = array('username' => $user, 'password' => $pass);
       $url = "http://localhost:8585/auth/session";


       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 75);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form_data);

       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);

       echo "result $result";
```

on the service site it produce a error like this:

```
@FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form_data);
```

with this line

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($form_data));`

the reason you got an error is you are sending an array, but what you need to send is a urlencoded string. refer this:
               http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php